# Accessing Api's using managed identity in Azure Web Api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

I am trying to connect to web Api's. I wish to use managed identity to allow acces from source API to target API.

In source Api i run this code, in order to obtain an accesstoken:

```
token = await new ManagedIdentityCredential()
                   .GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new string[] {/*Scope here*/}));
```

The scope i the url of the second API, or with prefix app instead of Http.

When i run the code in the source app service, i get this error:

```
    ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed. Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
    Content: {"statusCode":500,"message":"An unexpected error occured while fetching the AAD
```

I am puzzeled about the 500 error, i would assume if I had misconfiugred anything I would get a 401.

Comment: please share your complete code

Comment: This is all the code needed to obtain an accesstoken, which currently fails.

Comment: refer https://awhnet.medium.com/securing-api-to-api-azure-app-services-using-managed-identity-ea02035c7d0d

Comment: Can you confirm, you configured the required permissions in AAD? Also the scope needs to be the client_id or identifier_uri of the target app.

Comment: Just did some additional testing, if i request Graph access (which it also has access to) and i get a token with the exact same code.